# Use before_body in Rmarkdown for a html document

Tags: yaml, r-markdown

I want to add an image (an html file called "Logo.html") at the top of another html document.
for that i use "before_body":

I save my Logo.html in the same file as my Rmarkdown and i get the following error when "kniting" my rmd: 
pandoc.exe: Logo.html: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

is there a specific place to put my "Logo.html"? do you know what is incorrect in my code?

output:

html_document:

```
include:

  before_body: Logo.html

fig_caption: true
code_folding: hide
```

Answer (score 3):

You must be careful with the indentation and nesting of the YAML parameters.
This works for me:

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      before_body: Logo.html
fig_caption: true
code_folding: hide
---
```

Comment: thank you, i realised that my file's name was named "Logo.htm" ...   i have another question i want my image be at right of my document, how could I do that?